# Removing all float with the range of .01 to .99

Tags: python

I have a simple python program

After the division, it shows the end value but I want to not show the .01

```
from __future__ import division

number = int(133)
output = float(0)
divideNumber = int(1)

stop = false

while stop == false
   halfNumber = number / 2
  output =  number / divideNumber 
  output = round(output, 2)

  if ".0" in str(output):
    if "0.1" in str(output) or "0.2" in str(output ) or.... "0.9" in str(output): 
      #Do Nothing
  else: 
      #Do Nothing
    else: 
      print str(number) + " / " + divideNumber + " = "str(output)

  divideNumber += 1

  if divideNumber < halfNumber:
    break
  else: 
    #Do Nothing
print "Goodbye"
```

if I run it, this is the result:

```
133 / 1 = 133.0
133 / 7 = 19.0
133 / 11 = 12.09
133 / 12 = 11.08
133 / 19 = 7.0
133 / 22 = 6.05
133 / 33 = 4.03
133 / 43 = 3.09
133 / 44 = 3.02
133 / 64 = 2.08
133 / 65 = 2.05
133 / 66 = 2.02
```

Goodbye

My expected result is

```
 133 / 1 = 133.0
 133 / 7 = 19.0
 133 / 19 = 7.0
 Goodbye
```

Is my "if" statement wrong? I did not receive any errors!

Comment: There are numerous issues with the code above, not the least of which is the while loop should say 'while stop==False:'. Also, no need to say int(133), just say 133. No need to say float(0), say 0.0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right, you need to skip all numbers with non-round numbers. This check should be something like:

```
from math import floor

if (output - floor(output))>0: # skip
    continue
```

Answer (score 3):

*"I have a simple python program"*

This is not a simple program.

If you want to show the results with one decimal digit, use this:

```
print '{:.1f}'.format(133./19.)
```

this prints

```
7.0
```

If you want to test whether one **integer** number divides another:

```
if not x%y:
    # y divides x
```

Comment: I do want it to show the others too. I would prefer it to show " 133 / 1 = 133.0
 133 / 7 = 19.0
 133 / 19 = 7.0
 Goodbye"

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function like this, as something like `133.0==133` is `True`:
:

```
In [1]: def func(x,y):
   ...:     a=float(x)/float(y)
   ...:     return int(a)==a
   ...: 

In [2]: func(133,1)
Out[2]: True

In [4]: func(133,11)
Out[4]: False

In [5]: func(133,12)
Out[5]: False

In [6]: func(133,19)
Out[6]: True
```

with `division`  imported from `__future__`:

```
In [14]: from __future__ import division

In [15]: def func(x,y):
    return x/y == int(x/y)
   ....: 

In [16]: func(133,1)
Out[16]: True

In [17]: func(133,11)
Out[17]: False

In [18]: func(133,12)
Out[18]: False

In [19]: func(133,19)
Out[19]: True
```